# Django social allauth with JWT token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-allauth

I made registration via social networks using the allauth library.

Added the necessary settings:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email".
```

and applications:

```
"allauth", #registration
"allauth.account", # registration
"allauth.socialaccount", # registration
"allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk", # registration via VK.
```

and in urls.py I also wrote:

```
url(r"^accounts/", include("allauth.urls"))
```

The problem is that sometimes the provider after registration may not provide an email.
And my users are identified using mail.

Signup:
I want the user to be redirected to a page with an email entry and send a confirmation link to this email after the suppliers confirm the entered data is correct.

Signin:
I want to return the JWT token to the user after confirming the providers that the entered data is correct

How to implement a signin/signup system in Django DRF JWT with allauth library?
(apparently I need to write custom views, but I tried - unsuccessfully)